# CMS Images Not Responsive

Tags: magento-2.1, rwd, cms-pages, media-images

I've added an image to my front page. It has no width or height defined in the image tag.

When I resize the browser window it is responsive until the window is mobile size and the menu disappears.

Then the image completely disappears and all you see is a white screen beneath the header.

I've tried various things like putting it into a div and applying a style of width 100% and height auto but same issue of having it disappear. Help!

I've tried 
    div.sale img {
        float: left;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

and various combinations of this including removing the float, tried display: block;

[image: front page image disappears]

Comment: Add style for image:
`max-width: 100%;`

Comment: already tried that and it did not work

Comment: If you have owl slider on that page then you have to change style for `.columns {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: based off of magento blank with no changes to theme except in header and background img. no owl slider.

Comment: Feeling pretty stupid. Apparently I do have an owl slider. @Dipesh Rangani. '.columns { display: block; }' worked

Answer (score 1):

You tried below?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<img src="your img source" style="width:100%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. it was the .columns { display: block; } that i needed.

Comment: okay, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with img `{ width: 100%; height: auto; }` but this is dependent on the parent element, if the parent doesn't have a width set, the image does not have a reference for it's own width

Answer (score 0):

If you have owl slider on that page then you have to change style for `.columns`

```
.columns { display: block; }
```